# Currency formatting not working

Tags: swift

I have just updated to the GM of Xcode 6 and I am currently going through and fixing issues.

I have an issue with a particular part of my code that I have been struggling to fix. Basically I used to have this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    currencyFormatter.currencyCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: NSLocaleCurrencyCode)!
}

func textFieldDidChangeValue(textField: UITextField) {
    //Automatic formatting for transaction value text field. Target is added above.
    var text = textField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.currencySymbol, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") // There is a special character here. This line is critical for european/other currencies.
    println(textField.text)

    textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber((text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0)
    currencyDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0
    //println(currencyDouble)
    valueEnter.alpha = 100
}
```

I had to change the code in viewDidLoad() as my app was crashing, to this:

```
let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    if let currencyCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol) as? String {
        currencyFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
        println(currencyFormatter.currencyCode) //Will display "$", for example, if your locale is set to USD
    }
```

The app no longer crashes however the formatting doesn't work. I've tried a few things but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You picked the wrong answer on your previous question. You're setting the `currencyCode`, using the `NSLocaleCurrencySymbol` value.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Sorry about that misunderstanding.

Comment: My bad, I put `NSLocaleCurrencySymbol` instead of `NSLocaleCurrencyCode` in my previous answer. Guido has the right answer for your previous question. Thanks guys for pointing out that (I edited my answer as a consequence). @user3746428: do Guido's comment solve your problem?

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the response anyway. Yup, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `currencyCode` using the `NSLocaleCurrencySymbol` value. This is, as the name would suggest, the wrong value. The correct value would be `NSLocaleCurrencyCode`.